# Xamarin Studio iOS assembly error

Tags: c#, ios, reference, xamarin.ios, .net-assembly

After I updated my Xamarin Studio (iOS) it gives me this error when trying to build/debug.

I ain't got no clue how to fix this, would appreciate some help

Error:

```
The type 'MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
Consider adding a reference to assembly 'monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I am using "AlexTouch.MBProgressHUD.dll" and I have added it to my usings.

Comment: Do you have MonoTouch.dll referenced in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public key token of `monotouch.dll` changed in Xamarin.iOS 6.2 (it's not `null` anymore).

You'll need to recompile bindings (or assemblies) that refers to `monotouch.dll` or use the tool ([from this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1475/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-ios-6-2-0#latest)) to update them.

Comment: I have this issue with ServiceStack Monotouch DLLs.  Does anyone have the correctly recompiled versions for Servicestack Monotouch 3.9.55 (as I can't use the tool on my Mac)? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoTouch